# javascript loop to check for every 15minutes

Tags: javascript, loops

Hi i am little bit confused to write this loop.
It should alert for every fifteen minutes stating with 0 mins.

```
var i = 0;
var l = 900;
var m = 90000;
for (i=i; i<=m; i++){
    alert(i+l);
    i=i+l;
}
```

Comment: do we really need to make it in a for loop? or we can do another way?

Comment: ok the answer of @janith is for you

Answer (score 7):

What you need is the [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method:

```
setInterval(function(){
    alert('hi');
},15*60*1000);
```

Comment: Yes, thanks chovy. @Elias Van Ootegem's answer explains this.

Comment: @janith: If you do decide to use (part of) my answer, I'd advise you to opt for the second approach, as it doesn't set globals, except for the one `intervalMgmt` object, and allows you to set and clear intervals several times, and much more (like changing the callback function and interval)

Answer (score 3):

```
window.setInverval(function(){
    alert("msg");
}, 1000*60*15);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using @janith's answer, I suspect your next question will be `how do I stop an interval`:

```
var intId = setInterval(function()
{
    alert('foo');
},15*60000);//assign to var
clearInterval(intId);//stops the interval
```

Or even better (and safer, without globals):

```
var intervalMgmt = (function(intId)
{
    var start = function(cb,time)
    {
        intId = setInterval(cb,time);
    };
    var stop = function()
    {
        clearInterval(intId);
    };
    return {start:start,stop:stop};
})();
intervalMgmt.start(function()
{
    console.log('foo');
},5000);//logs "foo" every 5 seconds
//some time later:
intervalMgmt.stop();//stops the interval
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
var i = 0;
var l = 900;
var m = 90000;

 var setIntervalConst = setInterval(function(){
      if(i > m){
       clearInterval(setIntervalConst ); return;
      }
      alert(i+l);
       i=i+l;
  },15*60*1000);
```